# How do I upgrade a Docker image in a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that runs on 2 images: an app and a postgres database. I composed the container using docker-compose. If I want to upgrade to a newer image of the app or the database, how do I do it without losing the data in the database? Do I just `docker rm container` and then run `docker-compose up` for both the app and the database? I am new to docker and self-hosting so I appreciate all help.

Comment: Could it be that you have played with the config files to change the port it listens to? https://miniflux.app/docs/configuration.html#port

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes turns out I used 8080:8888 initially and upon fixing it, it worked. But I lost all my data so I am wondering how would I go about it next to keep my data (I just changed the question). Thank you!